# parsing html file using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have extracted the html source code from a website using jquery. I am trying to extract link under a specific tag which is of the form `<p class="title"> <a href="some link ">` 
 I am trying to extract the link under a href.
To extract the html i did

```
$.get("link",function(data){ alert($data('p').attr('title')); }
```

data contains the html source code. 
The alert box shows as undefined. Is it not possible to extract the

tag with data in this format?
I am not able to get how to extract the link under the href tag. Please help

Comment: you are using data as function parameter an $data in your alert. These are 2 different variables...

Comment: Remember, "link" has to be on your same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original Solution (finds first link)

```
$.get("link",function(data){ alert($(data).find('p.title a').attr('href')); }
```

Modified Solution (finds all links)

```
$.get("link", function(data) {
    var links = [];

    $(data).find('p.title a').each(function() {
        links.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    alert(links.join(', '));
});
```

Comment: it works..but when there are multiple p tags with class title it extracts only the 1st one

Comment: You are going to have to loop through each one to get them then.  So `$(data).find('p.title a').each(function(){ alert($(this).attr('href'));});`

Comment: I added a `separator` argument to the `join()` method call.  I do not think you would need that, but just in case should try that.

Comment: its working now, one bracket missing was the problem ! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem, it gets confusing sometimes when you are using jQuery + AJAX :)  Glad you got it working.

Comment: I have got one more problem :) links contains all the links which i require. I want to go to each link and extract an image tag with a specific source.var imglink= $(links[0]).find('img src="/inline/content/image"'); is that right?

Comment: Could you post some more sample HTML?  I am not sure I quite understand what you are looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14873/discussion-between-user1019083-and-dana)

Answer (score 1):

From your example it looks like you should be doing this:

`$.get("link",function(data){ alert($(data).find('p.title a').attr('href')); }`

Comment: Never done that before.  We literally have the exact same answer :)

Comment: it works..but when there are multiple p tags with class title it extracts only the 1st one